# jQuery animation not running at the same time of slideDown

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I have the following code which works fine, however I would like the animation to happen at the same time when '.main_nav' slides down. At the moment '.slides_down' slides first and than '.multicolor' animates after. I need them to happen at the same time.

```
       function slideDown_Menu(){
                $('.top-nav').slideUp(300,function(){
                    $('.main_nav').slideDown('slow', function(){
                        $('.multicolor').animate({top: '203px'});
                        // $('.tab_wrapper').animate({ marginTop: '63px' }, 500, 'linear');
                    });
                });
        }
```

Comment: Please refer to jQuery's API documentation for reference on `.slideDown( [duration] [, callback] )` at http://api.jquery.com/slideDown/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So dont use callback function of slideDown:

```
function slideDown_Menu(){
                $('.top-nav').slideUp(300,function(){
                    $('.main_nav').slideDown('slow');
                     $('.multicolor').animate({top: '203px'});
                });
        }
```

Comment: I realised the mistake of using the call back function but there is still a bit of difference in terms of fractions of second between the 2.

Comment: Then try $('.multicolor').animate({top: '203px'},'slow');

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to http://api.jquery.com/slideDown/

Putting function as a second parameter in

```
$('.main_nav').slideDown('slow', function(){ ... });
```

means that you want to execute it when slideDown is **complete**